# How to get a Nativescript app on Apple Watch and use Health Data?

Tags: ios, nativescript, watchos

I'm trying to set up a basic nativescript app on Apple Watch 3 which reads Heart Rate data. I realize that I would need WatchKit, but how do I set up the app, Sidekick only gives the option of iPhone or iPad.
Also, what's the Nativescript way of writing companion code for the iPhone which will receive this data from the phone?

Comment: If the watch is synced with device, you can read the heart rate from [healthkit plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-health-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Watch Integration will be available in next {NS} release.

https://www.nativescript.org/roadmap-and-releases#releases